# How to suppress calling default argument function in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, default-value

I have a line of code like this:
`subparser.add_argument('--user', type=str, default=getpass.getuser(), help='User to run the Batch jobs as')`. When the command entered does not specify a `--user`, then the `getpass.getuser()` is called. However, calling `getpass.getuser()` could throw errors in testing mode, so the test fails before even reaching where it is supposed to test. Can anyone suggest how to suppress that default function from being called?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would `getpass.getuser()` throw errors in testing mode?

Comment: @wim The stacktrace looks like this:
```'--user', type=str, default=getpass.getuser(), help='User to run the Batch jobs as'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/getpass.py", line 169, in getuser
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 1001'```
Because none of the environment variable is set and it can't find a correct uid. I tried to set --user in argument, but the `getuser()` still gets called.